# Automatically make new box by reading from database

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a box with information that I read from database(news) , but I've got another database(categories) with the category of that box. If the categories are 7 I want to automatically make 7 box.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("tnews2") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");  

    $rowsPerPage = 2;


    $query1 = "SELECT id,name FROM categories  ORDER BY ID";
    $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query1."]");

    $query2 = "SELECT id,name,text,img,cat_id FROM news WHERE cat_id=2 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT  $rowsPerPage";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query2."]");
 ?>

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ ?>
            <?php for($i=0; $i<$row['id']; $i++){ ?>


            <div class="focusBussines" >
            <?php while ($rowB = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ ?>

        <a class="titleMini" href="categories.php?id=<?= $rowB['id'] ?>&cat_id=<?=$rowB['cat_id']?>">Бизнес</a>
        <?php } ?>

        <table class="table" width="100%">
            <?php while ($rowB2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 

                if($rowB2['cat_id'] == 2){ ?>

                <tr>
                    <td  align="left" width="150" >
                        <img class="pic" src="<?php echo $rowB2["img"];?>" height="120" width="120">
                    </td>
                <td  align="left" colspan="100%" id="title" ><a id="Zaglavie" href="novina.php?id=<?= $rowB2['id'] ?>&cat_id=<?=$rowB2['cat_id']?>" >  <?php echo $rowB2['name'];  ?></a></td>

                </tr>
                    <tr >
                        <td colspan="100%"><hr/> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } } ?>
            </table>
    </div>
<?php } } ?>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: why do you keep 'stopping' and 'starting' php?

Comment: I fixed it ... just remove <?php for($i=0; $i<$row['id']; $i++){ ?> but it printing my the name end text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem originates from those unnecessary opening/closing php statements (emphasize added):

```
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query2."]");
>>>>> ?> <<<<<
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){ >>>>> ?> <<<<<
    >>>>> <?php <<<<< for($i=0; $i<$row['id']; $i++){ >>>>> ?> <<<<<
```

This is the same as writing

```
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query2."]");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    for($i=0; $i<$row['id']; $i++){ ?>
```

and increases the readability and reduces possible errors due to missing open/close tags.

Comment: If we use html statements inside a php statement it will load from the server. But if it is used outside php tags it will load more faster as it is loading from the browser side. This is a good practice.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC Not sure if serious. Or if you just don't know *how* PHP actually works. It is always interpreted on the server and the resulting HTML sent to the client (nothing PHP related happens on "the browser side"). My question merely wanted to point out the unnecessary open/close statement structure _between_ PHP statements.

Comment: @ nietonfir If we put a text box inside an echo statement it will have to contact the server. but if we put it as a regular html it will load more faster as no server interpretation is needed.only php related things needs to be inside a php tage other htmls can be given outside the php tag. Hope you understood what I meant.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC I'm sorry, but I think you need to freshen up your terminology because your first sentence is plainly wrong. As for the rest, that's exactly what I wrote in my answer to your first comment. I'll clarify my sentence in the answer and leave this as is.